# Error messages are not sending to Rollbar dashboard using asp.net core 1.0.1 web api application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-1.0, rollbar

I'm using an asp.net core 1.0.1 web api project where Rollbar exception handling has implemented by using  "RollbarDotNet": "0.5.1" version. It was working fine as I expected before but now there is no exception has captured.

I have followed the below article. 
https://github.com/RoushTech/RollbarDotNet but still the exception will not send it to Rollbar dashboard.

Startup.cs

```
    public class Startup
        {
            public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
            {
                var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);         

                builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                Configuration = builder.Build();
            }
            public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {  
                services.AddRollbar();
                services.Configure<RollbarOptions>(options => Configuration.GetSection("Rollbar").Bind(options));
            }
            public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
            {
                app.UseRollbarExceptionHandler();

                app.UseMvc();
            }
        }
    appsettings.dev.json:
    {
      "Rollbar": {
        "AccessToken": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "Environment": "dev-idam"
      }
    }
Project.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "RollbarDotNet": "0.5.1"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

I expect to send an exceptions to Rollbar dashboard with respective people via email notification.[image: Rollbar Dashboard]

Comment: what do you mean by `Rollbar dashboard`? Share us a mini-demo which could reproduce your issue.

Comment: I have updated the Rollbar Dashboard here, where I can able to see the exceptions whenever an issue will occur in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Rollbar official SDK for .NET, .NetCore, Xamarin, etc.](https://github.com/rollbar/Rollbar.NET)

It is available as a group of Nuget packages:

- [Rollbar core module](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rollbar/)
- [Rollbar Middleware and other extensions for
  .Net Core Asp.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rollbar.NetCore.AspNet/)
- [Rollbar for Asp.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rollbar.Net.AspNet/)
- [Rollbar for Asp.Net MVC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rollbar.Net.AspNet.Mvc/)
- [Rollbar for Asp.Net WebApi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rollbar.Net.AspNet.WebApi/)
- [Rollbar for NLog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rollbar.PlugIns.NLog/)
- [Rollbar for Serilog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rollbar.PlugIns.Serilog/)
- [Rollbar for Log4net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rollbar.PlugIns.Log4net/) [Rollbar for MSEntLib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rollbar.PlugIns.MSEnterpriseLibrary/)

Comment: It got resolved once I upgrade my asp.net core web API project version along with Rollbar official SDK. Thanks for your suggestion @AKornich